# PHP exec() results in stripped lines/columns

Tags: php, width, exec, column-width

I execute shell-scripts via PHP's exec() function. The result is then displayed. Executing `dmesg` works like a charm, however executing `ps axu` outputs lines that are cut at 80 characters, like the following:

```
webservd   731  0.0  0.217812 5100 ?        S   May 19  0:00 /usr/php/bin/php-c
root       352  0.0  0.1 6344 3396 ?        S   May 19  0:10 /usr/lib/inet/ntpd
```

Any idea how I can avoid that width-restriction?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the option w to ps to disable line clipping.

Answer (score 0):

`ps` has [output modifiers](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps). You need one of these:

> -w
>
> Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.
>
> w
>
> Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.

Just add `ww`:

```
ps axuww
```